# How do I solve this?

Tags: flash, adobe

This is my code: 
http://pastie.org/1795351

I want this code to be able to remove af or bf if its touching ground. But I can't do that because "cant define property of bf" and af.

And I need to have it outside the other functions because I will have alot of code otherwise.

```
if(bf || af.hitTestObject(Basket)){
removeChild(bf || af);
}
```

Comment: Your link is broken - it doesn't lead anywhere. Further, you might consider renaming your question to reflect the problem you're having.

Comment: Looks like their nameservers aren't responding - I did a dig +trace from my command line and got nothing. The site's probably in your cache, which is why the link is working for you. It might come back up within the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkGroundHit(object Sprite):void
{
    if (ground.hitTest(object))
    {
         object.parent.removeChild(object);
    }
}

checkBasketHit(af);
checkBasketHit(bf);
```

I see no ground in your code to test against, maybe you missed it?